# How to send the requests to server to get the data for my modal dialog in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, modal-dialog

I am using ember-modal-dialog addon for the dialog  features in my app.Now the data shown in dialog is requested from server.So every time I click on button it should request the server and show the received data.

feed.hbs

```
{{#each feedResult as |feed|}}

<p {{action "toggleModal" feed.fivers_pk }}> {{feed.numFives}} </p>
   {{#if isShowingModal}}
       {{#modal-dialog close="toggleModal"}}
           <p>People who Hi-Fived this</p>
           <img src = "images/shape-line-separator.png">

                 Data from server

       {{/modal-dialog}}
   {{/if}}

{{/each}
```

Controller.js(feed.js)

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import raw from 'ic-ajax';

const { service } = Ember.inject;

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
     session:service('session'),
     isShowingModal: false,
     fivers:[],
     feedResult:Ember.computed('model',function() {

            SOME MANIPULATION WITH DATA
     }),

     actions:{

      toggleModal: function(fiverpk) {
         this.toggleProperty('isShowingModal');
         console.log(fiverpk);
         raw({
            url: "http://example.com/api/photos/"+fiverpk+"/fivers/",
            type: 'GET',
        });
  }, 
}
});
```

I am able to make the request to server and receive the data through the ajax call in actions.But where and how should I store it.So that I can use it in modal-dialog when it opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do nothing with the returned result from the AJAX request. You could do something like the below

```
raw({
    url: "http://example.com/api/photos/"+fiverpk+"/fivers/",
    type: 'GET',
}).then(function(result) {
   // add the relevant part of the result to the modal
});
```

Comment: That what I am not able to do.The response from server is an array of objects.something like [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}].Now how and where should I store so that I can use it in my hbs